# Problems using the python WConio library

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the WConio library for python, but when I import it, it gives this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "WConioExample.py", line 15, in
>   < module>
>       import WConio   File "d:\tools\development\python2.5\lib\site-packages\WConio.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       **from _WConio import * ImportError: DLL load failed with error code 193**

I've installed `WConio-1.5.win32-py2.5.exe` and made sure the _WConio.pyd file exists. I'm using it on Win7.

I have searched for this problem, but the results were of no good use.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382(VS.85,loband).aspx

Comment: I already have found what that error meant.

Comment: More details: [\[SO\]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: \[WinError 193\] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546).

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you've installed 32 bit library on 64 bit system.

Comment: Hmm, this could be. I'm using a 64bit version of win7. Should I build it myself then, from the py2.0 sourcecode? Or will that give any problems when using py2.5

Comment: Why python 2.0 sourcecode when you can compile the source for the latest version?